# Fatal error: Class 'RecursiveRegexIterator' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, socialengine

I recently did a fresh install of SE4 and after setting the folder permissions, I kept getting the following error: Fatal error: Class 'RecursiveRegexIterator' not found Adapter.php on line 248

I would be very grateful if anyone familiar with SocialEngine 4, could assist me in this issue

Many Thanks
Sammy

Comment: What version php are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SE4` uses [`RecursiveRegexIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveregexiterator.php) which is  `PHP 5 >= 5.2.0`

You would need to upgrade your PHP version for it to work .... and please note that `PHP 5.1.6` is no longer supported.

Comment: can't seem to update my PHP, I tried Yum update and keep getting an error can't join environment.  Social Engine 4 was working before, all i did was download a fresh copy to install and that is when things started to go wrong

Comment: Thanks Baba, I had to update my PHP and Operating system and now everything is working fine. Many Thanks :)